# How to add Submit button to AsyncFileUpload control?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, file-upload, ajaxcontroltoolkit

`AsyncFileUpload` control start uploading file as soon as user select file. But normal behavior is, first user browse file  then click `submit button` then file uploading should start. How to achieve this functionality in case of `AsyncFileUploadf` control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of the `AsyncFileUpload` is that it uploads the file(s) asynchronously. Allowing the user to select other files while the control continues to upload the files already selected.

If you want browse for file, then submit file functionality, then you should use the standard FileUpload control.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you need to download the source, and modify the AsyncFileUpload tool's source code.